# Display Hebrew in a Java Jar Using Swing

Tags: java, swing, fonts, utf, hebrew

I'm building a program that is using Java Swing for GUI, and is supposed to show items according to data in a database.
I'm working in IntelliJ Idea.

When I work from the IDE and press the "run" or "debug" buttons, the GUI starts up fine and everything works well.

[image: Correct Hebrew display]

However, after building an artifact (exporting to a JAR), when running the output JAR, I can't see Hebrew letters, for example:

[image: Hebrew letters displayed wrong]

The above pictures are of exactly the same database (background colors are randomized).

The code building the above JLabels:

```
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 panel.setOpaque(false);
 Dimension size = new Dimension(this.getWidth(), TeaserPanel.NAME_HEIGHT);
 this.setPreferredSize(size);
 this.setMinimumSize(size);
 this.setMaximumSize(size);

 // The name label.
 JLabel name_label = new JLabel(this.m_item.getName(), SwingConstants.LEFT);

 // Set the font of the label (size, style & font type).
 Font font = Configuration.MAIN_ENGLISH_FONT.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, NAME_FONT_SIZE);
 if (font.canDisplay(this.m_item.getName().codePointAt(0)))
 {
     name_label.setFont(font);
 }
 else
 {
     name_label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, NAME_FONT_SIZE));
 }
 panel.add(name_label);
 panel.revalidate();
```

So, in essence, when m_item.getName() is a Hebrew string, it is shown wrong.

What could be causing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"What could be causing this?"* The font does not support those characters. Search on `[fonts] [java]` for solutions.

Comment: You're deriving a font from whatever `MAIN_ENGLISH_FONT` is, instead of from a real font, so: start with actually using a font that supports hebrew instead of relying on "whatever is running this jar" magic.

Comment: A flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. Sorry, I can't speak java nor Hebrew so please admit following example written in Python: `'שלי'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')` returns `'×©×œ×™'`.